# How to add data retrieved from remote MySql DB to a MatrixCursor

Tags: android, json, parsing, cursor

Hi i would like to ask for assistance on how to populate my ListView i retrieve data from a remote database and add it to a matrix cursor however it only adds the final record that was retrieved therefore my list only has one record i don't know whether its my loop or how I'm adding data to the cursor please help

here is my current code

> ```
>   try{
>               JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
>
>               for(i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
>                       json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
>
>                          _id = json_data.getInt("_id");
>                          rec_words = json_data.getString("words");
>                          rec_word = json_data.getString("word");
>                          rec_word2 = json_data.getString("word2");
>                          rec_description = json_data.getString("definition");
>
>                            //   cursor.addRow(items);    
>                         // System.out.println(mld.query);
>
>                       //  items.add(_id);
>                        // items.add(rec_word);
>                         //items.add(rec_word2);
>                         //items.add(rec_words);
>                         //items.add(rec_description);
>                         //System.out.println(items);
>                       final String[] matrix  = { "_id","words","word", "word2","definition"};
>                          cursor = new MatrixCursor(matrix);
>
>
>                      //cursor.addRow(new Object[] {json_data.getInt("_id"),json_data.getString("words"),json_data.getString("word"),json_data.getString("word2"),json_data.getString("definition")});
>
>                        cursor.addRow(new Object[] {_id,rec_words,rec_word,rec_word2,rec_description});
>
>
>
>                        // cursor.addRow(items);
>                       Log.i("log_tag","_id: "+json_data.getInt("_id")+
>                               ", word: "+json_data.getString("word")+
>                               ", word2: "+json_data.getString("word2")+
>                               ", definition: "+json_data.getString("definition")
>                       );                    
>
>                       //Get an output to the screen
>
>                 returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
>                 //System.out.println(returnString);
>
>               }
>       }catch(JSONException e){
>               Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Use this code to loop through your cursor:</strike>

```
if (myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        //get cursor data
    } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

**EDIT:**
Remove the line `cursor = new MatrixCursor(matrix);`

Comment: Thanks man this worked like a charm hard to believe it was such a small problem much gratitude